# How to groupBy in Spark using two columns and in both directions

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to group my dataframe elements, basing on two columns in both directions.
This is a sample of used dataframe

```
val columns = Seq("src","dst")
val data = Seq(("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "A"),("A", "B"), ("B", "A"), ("B", "A"),("A", "C"), ("B", "A"), ("C", "D"),("D", "C"), ("A", "C"), ("C", "A"))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val dff = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(columns:_*)
```

When I use simple groupBy on two columns I get this result

```
dff.groupBy("src","dst").count().show()
+---+---+-----+
|src|dst|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  B|  C|    1|
|  D|  C|    1|
|  A|  C|    2|
|  C|  A|    2|
|  C|  D|    1|
|  B|  A|    3|
|  A|  B|    2|
+---+---+-----+
```

I want group columns where `src` and `dst` are the same in the other direction(for example grouping **A**,**C** and **C**,**A** together, **A**,**B** and **B**,**A** together...).
The desired result is like that

```
+---+---+-----+
|src|dst|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  B|  C|    1|
|  D|  C|    2|
|  A|  C|    4|
|  B|  A|    5|
+---+---+-----+
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array column with `array` containing your two group by column, sort this array and group by this array column, as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, array_sort, col, count, first}

val result = dff.withColumn("group", array_sort(array(col("src"), col("dst"))))
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg(first("src").as("src"), first("dst").as("dst"), count("group").as("count"))
  .drop("group")
```

`result` dataframe is as follow:

```
+---+---+-----+
|src|dst|count|
+---+---+-----+
|A  |B  |5    |
|C  |A  |4    |
|B  |C  |1    |
|C  |D  |2    |
+---+---+-----+
```

If you don't have `array_sort` method (available in spark 2.4), you can use `when` condition to reorder your two columns `src` and `dst`, as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, when}

val result = dff
  .withColumn("first", when(col("dst") < col("src"), col("src")).otherwise(col("dst")))
  .withColumn("second", when(col("dst") >= col("src"), col("src")).otherwise(col("dst")))
  .drop("src", "dst")
  .withColumnRenamed("first", "src")
  .withColumnRenamed("second", "dst")
  .groupBy("src", "dst")
  .count()
```

However, this second method only works for two columns

Answer (score 2):

Another way without using arrays, you can group by `greatest` and `least` functions like this:

```
dff.groupBy(
    least($"src", $"dst").as("src"),
    greatest($"src", $"dst").as("dst"),
).count().show

//+---+---+-----+
//|src|dst|count|
//+---+---+-----+
//|  B|  C|    1|
//|  A|  C|    4|
//|  C|  D|    2|
//|  A|  B|    5|
//+---+---+-----+
```

You can change the order of `src` and `dst` if the groupby if you want the greatest value to be in the `src` column for example.